# How can I calculate confidence intervals for epsilon-squared (Effect size for Kruskal-Wallis test) in R?

Tags: r, epsilon, kruskal-wallis

I'd like to calculate the confidence intervals for the epsilon-squared effect size statistic in R. Here is the code I'm using to calculate the epsilon-squared value:

```
#set up two vectors, a numerical vector and a factor vector (grouping variable)
x=c(3,2,4,7,4,6,9,2,3,4,1,0,8,6,9,5,3,3,6,7,8,2,8,9)
y=as.factor(c(rep("cond1",12),rep("cond2",12)))

#run kruskal-wallis test
kruskal.test(x~y)
library(rcompanion)
df=data.frame(x,y)

#calculate epsilon squared
epsilonSquared(x = df$x, 
           g = df$y)
```

This gives me my effect size. But the function only outputs a single figure. How can I calculate the confidence intervals of the effect size, please?

Answer (score 2):

You can read the help, what I just did:

> ci 
>   If TRUE, returns confidence intervals by bootstrap. May be slow.

```
epsilonSquared(x = df$x, 
               g = df$y,ci = T)

  epsilon.squared lower.ci upper.ci
1           0.185  0.00479     0.54
```

Comment: Thank you! This returned a single value for me - until I updated the package! Now it returns CI values - thank you so much

Comment: you are welcome. Don't hesitate to accept the answer if it indeed answered the question